# Process Builder to update related records with sharing settings problems

Tags: process-builder, userrecordaccess

I'm trying to use Process Builder to update related records but it update records even if the user isn't able to see those records.

Based in a field change from a object I'm updating all the related records from it, even if the user who triggered the process builder has no access to the record. There is a known workaround for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior, Process Builder flows [always run in system mode](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_distribute_context.htm&type=5), so they do not respect sharing rules or field-level security configurations. If you need an automated declarative process that will obey restrictions on record-level access, then you should use an autolaunched Flow, which enables you to specify the context in the Flow version properties:
[image]